# How do I print values in my list if it meets my requirements?

Tags: python, list

I started learing Python a few weeks ago and I'm looking for some help on lists. I want to be able to print values from my list if they contain less than 5 characters.

I have tried messing around with the `len` function and I think thats the way to go but I've never really used it only ever heard of it.

Below is my awful attempt at using the `len` function

```
my_list_1 = ["boy", "girl", "woman", "man" , "person"]

total = 0
for item in my_list_1:
    if  total == len(item) < 5:
        print (item)
```

Before I used `len` and the "total" variable I think the computer was getting confused because I'm basically asking it if a string is less than an integer but I'm not sure how to get around that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get rid of `total`:

```
my_list_1 = ["boy", "girl", "woman", "man" , "person"]

for item in my_list_1:
    if len(item) < 5:
        print (item)
```

In the original version, `total` was `0`, and the comparison `total == len(item) < 5` was equivalent to `total == len(item) and len(item) < 5`, so it was only true if `len(item)` was zero.

Answer (score 2):

As per your code the `if` block will execute only when length of value in a list is `0`

```
for i in my_list_1:
    if len(i)<5:
        print(i)
```